# Java inner/anon classes

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I'm stuck on this question where we need to instantiate the C class through A

```
class A{
  static class B{}
  static class C{ B b;
    C(B b){this.b=b;}
    int foo(){return 42;}
  }
}
public class Exercise{

  public static void main(String [] arg){
    assert ([???].foo()==42);
  }
}
```

Obviously we need to instantiate the C class within the A class, however I tried doing
something like `A.C(new B b)` and a few other variations, but I can't seem to figure it out, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an instance of `B`, to instantiate `C`

```java
A.B b = new A.B();
A.C c = new A.C(b);
assert c.foo() == 42;
```

Or, simplified.

```java
assert new A.C(new A.B()).foo() == 42;
```

If a class contains no constructor, an empty constructor is inferred.